# unable to read data from a card reader

Tags: android

I am using a card reader to read a particular information from the card.I am working it on 3 devices namely, Galaxy Ace-5830,Galaxy Y-5360 & a device from Motorola,dont exactly know its name. 
When the app is deployed on 5360,it works fine and reads all the information correctly.When deployed on 5830 the reader is not detected and on Motorola the reader is detected but it fails to read all the information.Please help for the same.
The above issue arises with custom app(The one I made)& the demo one the manufacturer has provided.

Comment: this stuf will solved only by looking the code you tried. Can you post your code?

Comment: No code, no description of what the app does. Solution is also from the OP without any details. Hardly useful on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys the issue has been resolved.
The API was supporting the motorola device. Integrated the new API and it has started working. :)